# C++ web framework like spring for Java

Tags: java, c++, spring, frameworks

Is there any web framework in C++ which is like Spring for Java, i am currently working on an application which is in the web domain. Our existing applications are all developed in c++, and we are looking for some framework which has a small learning curve and provides exciting features. Has anyone come across such a framework. Please let me know.

Comment: Have a look at this similar thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework

Comment: Spring is not a web framework, Spring MVC is. Hence, DI is a Spring IoC thing, not of Spring MVC. IMO, you should say Spring MVC, as you are interested in web frameworks. Or ask for IoC container, altogether.

Comment: I think PHP started as a C++ web framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [**ffead-cpp**](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/) while browsing similar threads, can anyone evaluate this framework or has any idea whether this would be a suitable choice. I think it already answers a few of my questions. Can you guys comment?

Comment: the framework is sill in the initial phase, but i love the way its designed, so it would serve as a good starting point.

Answer (score 8):

If its DI you are looking for; Dependency injection in C++ is not really done a lot, because although you can inject a pointer in to a class, its not easy to say who's gonna free it. There is already a SO [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352885/dependency-injection-in-c) .

Comment: SO doesn't host discussions :)

Comment: @LimitedAtonement SO may wish that is so, but they certainly host discussions

Answer (score 5):

I think the opensource project 'Drogon' is what you want. Drogon can be found in [github](https://github.com/an-tao/drogon), Here's the descript of Drogon:

Drogon is a C++14/14-based HTTP application framework. Drogon can be used to easily build various types of web application server programs using C++. Drogon's main application platform is Linux, it also supports Mac OS/UNIX. Its main features are as follows:

- Use a non-blocking I/O network lib based on epoll (kqueue under MacOS/FreeBSD) to provide high-concurrency, high-performance network IO;
- Provide a completely asynchronous programming mode;
- Support Http1.0/1.1 (server side and client side);
- Based on template, a simple reflection mechanism is implemented to completely decouple the main program framework, controllers and views.
- Support cookies and built-in sessions;
- Support back-end rendering, the controller generates the data to the view to generate the Html page, the view is described by a "JSP-like" CSP file, the C++ code is embedded into the Html page by the CSP tag, and the drogon command-line tool automatically generates the C++ code file for compilation;
- Support view page dynamic loading (dynamic compilation and loading at runtime);
- Provide a convenient and flexible routing solution from the path to the controller handler;
- Support filter chains to facilitate the execution of unified logic (such as login verification, Http Method constraint verification, etc.) before controllers;
- Support https (based on OpenSSL);
- Support WebSocket (server side and client side);
- Support JSON format request and response, very friendly to the Restful API application development;
- Support file download and upload;
- Support gzip compression transmission;
- Support pipelining;
- Provide a lightweight command line tool, drogon_ctl, to simplify the creation of various classes in Drogon and the generation of view code;
- Support non-blocking I/O based asynchronously reading and writing database (PostgreSQL and MySQL(MariaDB) database);
- Support asynchronously reading and writing sqlite3 database based on thread pool;
- Support ARM Architecture;
- Provide a convenient lightweight ORM implementation that supports for regular object-to-database bidirectional mapping;
- Support plugins which can be installed by the configuration file at load time;
- Support AOP with build-in joinpoints.

Answer (score 5):

I would also recommend [Oat++](https://oatpp.io/) which is designed exactly for your use case:

- same project structure as Java Spring
- cross-platform
- Supports swagger
- Authorization flow
- zero dependency

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I know of -- and I have no first-hand experience, I've only heard about it -- is a framework called [Autumn](http://code.google.com/p/autumnframework/).

Answer (score 1):

I tried RESTINIO modern c++ web framework..
This is well designed. Worth a try.
https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio